# How Can I stop my Fixed Sidebar on Footer

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with my sidebar... it is in a fixed div so that it scrolls along with the page... however when it comes to the bottom of the page. on smaller browsers my sidebar overlaps with the footer which has an id of "sub"

This is my sidebar css...

```
.sidebar.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 210px;
}
```

How can I stop this from overlapping my footer?

Comment: work on your footer like padding-left or padding-right.it may be easier.

Comment: Try to use z-index `.sidebar.sticky { z-index:100;} #sub{z-index:50;}`

Answer (score 0):

have a `margin-bottom` property in your .sidebar css. Suppose your footer has `20px` height set the css as `margin-bottom:20px;`

Edit: you can also set **bottom:20px;**

**Fiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/WCuq3/